# ASP.NET MVC3 Aspnetdb Sql Production Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-connection, aspnetdb

I created a fully functioning web application (MVC MusicStore, downloaded from here: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/).

The application created an ASPNETDB.MDF file, and a MusicStoreDB.mdf file.
I used SQL Server Management 2008 R2.

The problem is that after I deploy the application on a host server,
when clicking on "Register" link, the default error page is displayed.
When trying to log in, the default error page is displayed yet again.
It appears that the host server (which is SQL 2008 compatible) can read data from the MusicStoreDB.mdf file, but has no access to the ASPNETDB.MDF file. It is not possible to log in or register users.

I did change the connection string in the web.config file to the host server address, it works fine.
I also created the ASPNETDB tables in the MusicStoreDB by using aspnet_regsql, but the errors persist.
Also, the MusicStoreDB file contained no data after Publish (though there is sample data in a cs file). I know the host server can read data from this file because I manually added data through a local SQL server.

I have two questions:
a. What are the steps to correctly deploy the application and databases so that it would be possible to register and log in? How can the *both* mdf files work in consort?
b. How can the data in the SampleData.cs file be recreated in the MusicStoreDB.mdf file?

I haven't been able to find an answer over the web, though I've been searching for a week...

Comment: Did you set up permissions on the DB?

Comment: What do you mean by the 'default error page'?

Comment: Peter: No, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: StanK: As far as I understand, I had to set an error page in the Layout folder, which would be displayed if any error occurs.